# Angular 2 can't resolve all parameters for service

Tags: angular, service, inject

I have two services: LoginService and UserService. I am trying to inject UserService into LoginService and the app won't run.

In the console, I have the error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: ([object Object],
>   ?). at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError
>   (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:7156:33) at
>   SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor]

**this is my LoginService:**

```
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(public _http: Http,public us:UserService) {
  }
```

**and UserService:**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
    constructor(private _http: Http , public _ls: LoginService) {

    }
```

**angular module:**

```
import {LoginService} from './services/login.service';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,


  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

  ],
  exports: [BrowserModule, SlimLoadingBarModule],
  providers: [UserService, LoginService, appRoutingProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: please add the angular module and your `UserService` code.

Comment: You just created a circular dependency

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have a circular reference.

Your `UserService` requires `LoginService`, and `LoginService` requires `UserService`.

Remove one of the dependencies. E.g. refactor your UserService so that it does not require a reference to LoginService

Comment: exactly , what is the solution ?

Comment: Remove one of the dependencies. E.g. refactor your UserService so that it does not require a reference to LoginService

Comment: this is the one possible solution ?

Comment: Yes - thats the _only_ solution.

Answer (score 3):

As the other posted mentioned a circular dependency... you may consider using `forwardRef()` to resolve this issue.

In a nutshell, we can inject a Forward Reference instead of the real service. So the service injection will be deferred. Thus the circular dependency is solved.

Here is a code sample:

```
import {Component, Inject, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Favourite framework: {{ name }}</h1>'
})
class AppComponent {
  name: string;

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => NameService)) nameService) {
    this.name = nameService.getName();
  }
}

class NameService {
  getName () {
    return "Angular";
  }
}
```

You can check [this page](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/03/forward-references-in-angular-2.html) for further details.

Comment: Can you include the necessary parts of the forum post in your question? It is always recommended to include the actual answer rather than referring with a link

Comment: I think it should be something more like this: `constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => NameService)) nameService: NameService) { this.name = nameService.getName(); }`